# html to pdf convertion in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to convert a html page as it is to a pdf format in asp.net 3.5.
I have many images and tables.The alignment of these images and tables should not be changed while conveting to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The [iTextSharp library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) can do this. Here's some [example code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Comment: @ItextSharp will not be able to epxort images

Comment: @Muhammad: [What are you talking about?](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=10)